# Closure memory leaks

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, closures

I'm interested in the possibility in memory(unneeded reference) leaks of memory leaks in garbage collected languages

caused by variables caught in closures which are stored
(perhaps as part of an object system or as part of building actions based on input to be evaluated later).

Are there any languages where this sort of thing is somewhat common? If so what are the patterns to watch out for in those languages to prevent it?

Comment: If it's an unneeded reference then it's your responsibility as the programmer to ensure that it's de-referenced and/or that you ensure you don't create references with scopes larger than necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the closure is referenced, the captured variables will be kept. As a result, you need to be careful about where you create references to those closures.

Event handlers that are not unsubscribed are a potential source of many types of leaks. However, I can't really think of any generic patterns that will help you in every conceivable way you may be using closures :)

Comment: I was looking more towards a overview of specific problems you have had or heard about then something overly general.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really what you mean, but the garbage collector in Internet Explorer < 7 used not to be able to collect variables with circular references. This has not much to do with closures per se, but it turns out closures in javascript can create circular references quite easily.

I think a pattern like this would do

```
function foo() {
    var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    div.onclick = bar;

    function bar() {
        div.style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Now, whatever you do, the function `bar` references the variable `div`, and at the same time is assigned to a property of `div`.

As a consequence, it used to be necessary to put particular attention when using closures on IE to [avoid memory leaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In many languages, if multiple delegates are created that close over some variables in a given scope, every delegate which closes over any of those variables will close over all of them.  For example:

```
Action blah(Dictionary<string, int> dict, List<string> list)
{
  int i;
  list.ForEach( (st) => if (dict.Contains(st)) i++; );
  return () => Console.WriteLine("The value was {0}", i);
}
```

That method will create two delegates.  The first needs variables `dict` and `i`, and will be abandoned before the function exits.  The second only needs `i` but could be held indefinitely by the caller.  As long as the caller keeps the delegate returned by this method, the passed-in dictionary will not be collectible.

It would be possible for a compiler to avoid this issue by generating two closures, one of which held a `dict` and an `int[1]`, and the other of which just held an `int[1]`; both closures would hold a reference to the same `int[1]`, thus preserving the required semantics.  In practice, though, the extra costs associated with the excess captures.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in a Closure are not 'caught' but are simply still referenced, the GC isn't going to collect them until the reference is released. When the application terminates then any outstanding Closures are going to de-reference and any associated resource released. No memory leak as all allocated resources are released.

Comment: I think OP intended to use the term *captured*, not *caught*.

Comment: That's what I meant, I know that the memory won't be lost but it wont be collected because of the references to it. If I knew a better phrase then memory leak to refer to it(reference leak doesn't seem right).

Comment: @Roman A Taycher: I think the problem here is the work 'leak'. There just isn't a leak here. You could describe this as a footprint issue, in that the memory allocated to the variables is being retained but that's only because the closure may still be used. The GC has no easy way of knowing if your closure is going to be used again before the app terminates or the closure goes out of scope. With that in mind it does indicate that you need to be careful when assembling closures but the memory usage is fundamental to how the closure works.

Comment: @Lazarus: The term "memory leak" is IMHO properly applied in cases where an unbounded amount of memory may be allocated and become useless before being unrooted.  If repeating operation X, N times before doing Y will cause some multiple of N bytes to be simultaneously rooted, but the amount of *useful* information won't increase with N, and if there's no bound on how large N can get, that's a leak.  True, the memory might be released eventually, but there's no guarantee the system will survive that long.

Comment: @supercat: A "memory leak" stems from the days when memory was 'malloc'ed and 'free'd 'manually', at that point it was possible for an application to allocate a block of memory which it used during execution but then failed to free back to the OS when it terminated. Subsequent executions allocate new memory each time as the prior references have been lost in the ether, the memory cannot be safely recovered as there is no guarantee it's not still in use, it's leaked. What you describe is not a leak, it might result in an insufficient memory condition but on code end the memory will be released.

Comment: @Lazarus: In most "memory leak" scenarios, the OS knows precisely where all the "leaked" memory blocks are, but it has no way of knowing which if any may be safely freed.  On any reasonable OS, once a process ends, it will be safe to assume that the memory allocated by it won't be in use anymore, and thus the memory will be available for other use.  A program would still be considered to have a memory leak, however, if the only no limit to the quantity of abandoned memory that could accumulate during execution was the system's ability to supply it.

Comment: @Lazarus: In a conventional memory allocation, when user code asks the application's memory manager for some memory, the MM divvies up a chunk and return it; the MM will "own" the chunk behalf of the user code until such time as the user code indicates that it's no longer needed.  The MM owns the data, but it has no clue whether it's really of any use.  Memory leaks happen when the MM continues to own a block of memory on behalf of user code, unaware that the user code actually has no interest in it anymore but is never going to say so.

Comment: @Lazarus: The same situation arises with something like a subscription memory leak.  A long-lived or static object will hold a reference to an object *on behalf of someone else*, with the expectation that it will be told when the object is no longer needed.  If such notification never comes, the object may be held uselessly for an arbitrarily long time.

Comment: @supercat: In recent times, a process terminating or crashing as a result of running out of memory is unlikely to bring the whole system down and quickly identifiable as the culprit. True memory leaks are rare these days because of GC, your 'pseudo' memory leak  premise is valid in that it may look like and give the same outcome (in the short term) as a true memory leak but if the process dies because it's consumed all available memory... when it does, the memory is likely to be released through the GC or similar process. In the past, memory leaks caused trouble way beyond their process end.