# Finding Extension Javascript Leaks

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory-leaks, firefox-addon

I wrote an extension it's mainly JS with with C++ XPCOM Object.
It is fairly complex and long and I believe I have lots of memory leaks (using tools it shows leaks)

I'm lost.. :(

I just cannot find an easy, strait forward tool that can show me where my leaks generate from.

I did the following:
 read - https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance:Leak_Tools
 read various other articles on memory leaks.
 used - leak monitor plugin and leak guague (both show leaks).

How can I trace what causes the leaks in my js code? Is there some tool that can do this easily?
Is there an article that explains how to do it very strait forward?
Do I need to run FireFox Debug build? do I need to re-build firefox?

Please direct me as I'm completely lost :(

Thanks!
D.

Comment: Look for event listeners that might be getting added to something and then never getting removed, or things like that. Another thing to look out for is closures. When you create a closure, the inner function holds onto all the variables in the outer function. Looks like there is some good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245324/closure-memory-leaks

Comment: An extension completely written in JS shouldn't leak because of the various garbage and cycle collectors, so it's probably the C++ object making things tricky, especially if it has object members, as that can easily cause a cycle, which will leak.

Answer (score 0):

The [Firefox Memory Leak addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leak-monitor/) should tell you where it's leaking memory, no debug-build required.

I haven't worked with C++ in Firefox addons, but you might check your code with valgrind or another memory leak detector. Javascript can also cause memory problems, for example, using registerListener for a Firefox window without adding window.addEventListener("unload", function() {unregisterListener}) will cause a memory leak.